# Sign an iPhone configuration profile with Server certificate

Tags: ios, macos, openssl, x509certificate, mobileprovision

I already found a thread with a similar topic but I wasn't able to solve my problem this way, so I hope I get help here.

I'm trying to sign a iPhone config profile with my servers SSL certificate on Mac OS X:

```
openssl smime -sign -in company.mobileconfig -out signed.mobileconfig -signer server.crt -inkey server.key -certfile ca.crt -outform der -nodetach
```

Unfortunately I get the following error

```
unable to load certificate
```

I'm don't know what I'm doing wrong - I use the following certs:

server.crt:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHV.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

server.key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC, .....

sHK1......
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

ca.crt:
from http://www.startssl.com/certs/

All certificates are in the same folder 'iphone' I changed to with

```
ch /Volumes/Daten/.../iphone
```

So now I'm on

```
localhost:iphone Stefan$
```

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Regards
Stefan

Comment: *"[sign iPhone config]... with my servers SSL certificate on Mac OS X"* - this may not work. I think it depends on the Key Usage, Extended Key Usage and perhaps a Policy OID. I don't think a server certificate used for server authentication will have the proper bits set. But then again, I've never seen the Key Usage/Extended Key Usage/Policy OID Apple uses for the purpose.

Comment: I got this information from [link]http://www.rootmanager.com/iphone-ota-configuration/iphone-ota-setup-with-signed-mobileconfig.html and understood it like I wrote. Or was I wrong with this interpretation?

Comment: I don't know if it will work (or not). I don't know if you are correct (or not). I do know a little bit about PKI, and a server certificate is an end entity certificate used for authentication. So it should not be able to sign other certificates or provisioning profiles. If its allowed, then its yet another Apple security bug.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

`openssl smime -sign -signer cert.pem -inkey key.pem -certfile ca-bundle.pem -nodetach -outform der -in profile-uns.mobileconfig -out profile-sig.mobileconfig`

with ca-bundle.pem is the cert chain of a CA.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that you are using [Let's Enrcypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), you might get certificate.pem, privatekey.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem.

`-signer` should be certificate.pem which is the certificate of the server.

`-inkey` should be private.key of the server.

`-certfile` should be fullchain.pem

The chain.pem is the certificate chain including CA ROOT without certificate.pem, while fullchain.pem including everything.